# If $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$ for all $x\in D$ and $f$, $h$ are Riemann integrable, then so is $g$. True or False? (Check my work)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

If $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, and f and h are Riemann integrable on
[a,b], then so is g. True or false? Explain.

**A:** True
**Proof**:

Since $f\in R[a,b]$, $\bar \int_a^b{f} = \int_a^b\bar{f}$ (*That's supposed to be an underbar*), so $\int_a^b{f} \le U(P,f)$.
Since $h\in R[a,b]$, $\bar \int_a^b{h} = \int_a^b\bar{h}$, so $\int_a^b{h} \ge L(P,h)$.
Therefore, since $f(x)\le g(x) \le h(x)$, and $\int_a^b{f} \le U(P,f)$ and $\int_a^b{h}\ge L(P,f)$,
$U(P,f) \le \int_a^b{g} \le L(P,h)$ which implies $U(P,f) \le L(P,g) \le U(P,g) \le L(P,h)$

So $g(x)\in R[a,b]$.

Found it: [If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are Riemann integrable and $f(x)\leq h(x)\leq g(x)$, must $h(x)$ be Riemann integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85839/if-fx-and-gx-are-riemann-integrable-and-fx-leq-hx-leq-gx-must?rq=1)

Comment: Isn't a function like $1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, $0$ otherwise not Riemann integrable?  And it's bounded by lots of Riemann integrable functions

Comment: False. Take $f=0$, $h=1$, and $g$ to be your favorite bounded non-Riemann integrable function (like the indicator function of rationals).

Comment: To show Riemann integrability of $g$ on $[a,b]$, you must show that for all $\epsilon>0$, there is a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $$U(P,g)-L(P,g)<\epsilon.$$ What you've done isn't enough.

Answer (score 7):

It's wrong, take the Dirichlet function 
$$g(x)=\begin{cases} 
0 &  x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}\\
1 & x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
\end{cases}
$$
and $f(x)=0$ and $h(x)=1$, obviously $f\leq g\leq h$ and $f,h$ are riemann integrable

Answer (score 1):

False,

Let $I:=[0,1]$ and $g(x)=\chi_{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(x)$. Then $0\leq g\leq 1$ and $0$ and $1$  are both Riemann integrable in $I$ but $g$ isn't.

Why isn't it Riemann integrable? The upper Riemann sum is always $1$ and the lower sum is always $0$. Hence it can't be Riemann integrable